# Advice on managing a MERN app in production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern, pm2

I have a full-stack app I've developed myself using the MERN stack (+ socket.io and meilisearch). It has been deployed for a few months and started crashing intermittently with no discernible pattern. I was working on implementing PM2 to try and handle the crashes with just restarting as it appeared to be when the server was overloaded.

In trying to implement PM2 I may have discovered the source of the problem, which is that having built the React front-end and copied into a build fold, I am then running 'npm start' which in turn runs the command from my package.json file:

```
npx nodemon --exec npx babel-node src/server.js
```

In my research, it would appear that babel-node should NOT be used in a production environment. News to me as this is a technique I picked up in a tutorial many moons ago.

My question is: how do you recommend I deploy the app instead? I'm now questioning the whole approach I have in terms of copying the built frontend into the backend folder etc. Which transpiler option do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I stopped the app from using so much resource by reconfiguring the production following [these instructions](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server). I also encountered an issue with some dependencies not being present, specifically regeneratorRuntime. Helpful (short) [article found here](https://dev.to/hulyakarakaya/how-to-fix-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-doj) resolved that. A great side-benefit is that my app is noticeably faster and more responsive.

A more full answer to my deployment improvements can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73082353/handling-errors-in-mongodb-and-express).